# tornadofx data binding when using eBean ORM

Tags: ebean, tornadofx

using ebean how can i bind itemModelView with model

```html
@Entity
class Person(

):Model(){
    @Id var id:Long=0
    var name:String?=null
    var title :String?=null

    val idProperty = SimpleLongProperty(0)
    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty()
    val titleProperty = SimpleStringProperty()

    companion object Find : PersonFinder()
}

class PersonModel():ItemViewModel<Person>(){
    val name= bind {item?.nameProperty  }
    val title=bind {item?.titleProperty  }
}
```

the problem is the data lost and can't binding to model
it work if i replace
var name:String?=null
by
var name by property()
but by doing that eBean didn't add the column to table

thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me

```
@Entity
class Person(

):Model(){
    @Id var id:Long=0
    var name:String?=null
    var title :String?=null

    companion object Find : PersonFinder()
}

class PersonModel():ItemViewModel<Person>(){
    val name= bind(Person::name)
    val title=bind(Person::title)
}
```